# How to put text in a specific cell with Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula in Excel that puts some text in a specific cell?

For example I want F16 cell to have text "Sum total is:"

Before you answer "click on F16 and enter the desired text" the point of the question is that I do not know in advance that it is going to be F16.
Whether it is F12 or F24 is dependent upon FILTER function that produces a variable number of rows above "Total row"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `VSTACK()`:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(B1:B5,A1:A5="a"),VSTACK(x,"Sum total is:  "&SUM(x)))
```

Comment: I always like adding a blank row, but that's opinion based: `=LET(x,FILTER(B1:B5,A1:A5="a"),VSTACK(x,"","Sum total is:  "&SUM(x)))`

Comment: Your answer works and I have a workaround but what I do not understand ist why      <br/> 

=VSTACK(FILTER(PerformedTestsTable, PerformedTestsTable[Qty]>0, "Error"),{"","Total sum: ",145})    - 

works just fine as it is stacking filter table array with custom string + string + number array, however when I actually want to change that the last value of second stacked array references a named cell the code breaks done.

This does not work:<br/> 
=VSTACK(FILTER(PerformedTestsTable, PerformedTestsTable[Qty]>0, "Error"),{"","Total sum: ", MyNamedCell})